# Why does my like button only work on the first instance of a list in Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I follow Tango with Django's tutorial for adding the like button. I thought it worked, but it only seems to be working for the very first model instance in a list. You see, I have a view where all the objects in a list is displayed. My code looks like this:

**views.py**

```
def content_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/content_list.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**content_list.html** - the template

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p><strong id="like_count">{{post.votes}}</strong> points</p>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <button id="likes" data-post-id="{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-purple" type="button">
            <span>Upvote</span>
        </button>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

In **views.py**, I have another function which handles the post-liking:

```
@login_required
def like_post(request):
    post_id = None

    # Getting the id of the post from the template
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']

    likes = 0

    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id = int(post_id))
        if post:
            likes = post.votes + 1
            post.votes = likes
            post.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

And finally, my ajax file which does the actual work:

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var p_id;
    p_id = $(this).attr("data-post-id");
    $.get('/like_post/', {post_id: p_id}, function(data){
       $('#like_count').html(data);
       $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
```

My **urls.py** in my app folder has the following line in the url patterns:

```
# Liking a post
url(r'^like_post/$', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
```

What am I missing? The uproot button for the other posts don't hide either, which they should because of my ajax code. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: you should use class instead of id

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers : which id should I replace with classes, and why exactly? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: You are using a loop to create HTML elements (buttons) with same `id`. So when you select using jQuery, you get an object representing only the first element (since id is meant to be used as a unique identifier attribute). When using class, jQuery will return the set of all elements with the className.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers - Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying what was mentionned in comments, your server code could become:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p><strong id="like_count">{{post.votes}}</strong> points</p>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <button data-post-id="{{post.id}}" class="likes btn btn-purple" type="button">
            <span>Upvote</span>
        </button>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

And the javascript part is now:

```
$('.likes').click(function(){
    var p_id;
    p_id = $(this).attr("data-post-id");
    $.get('/like_post/', {post_id: p_id}, function(data){
       $('#like_count').html(data);
       $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but that does not work. For one thing, the like_count does not update the second time voting.

Comment: Well, it is really a seperate issue, but give me please some time I will be back in minutes try to figure out

Comment: Well I think you should do the same with like_count, replace with class name but this time you should replace also `$('.like_count').html(data);` with a jQuery select that targets only the sibling item, something like `$(this).prevAll(".like_count:first");`

Comment: This should work: `$(this).prev().find('.like_count').html(data);` fiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/LtuLr78k/

Comment: I agree with you Sir, yes I agree